# PDO Mysql erorr 1064

Tags: php, mysql

The query (As echo'd)

```
DELETE * FROM BlogPosts WHERE Id=?
```

The error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM BlogPosts WHERE Id='6'' at line 1' in /usr/www/maxtingle/Blog/System/Core/Functions.php:177 Stack trace: #0 /usr/www/maxtingle/Blog/System/Core/Functions.php(177): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /usr/www/maxtingle/Blog/System/Core/BlogPost.php(201): Functions\Database->Delete('*', 'Id=?', Array) #2 /usr/www/maxtingle/Blog/System/Blog.php(102): BlogPost->Delete() #3 [internal function]: Blog::DeletePost('6') #4 /usr/www/maxtingle/Blog/index.php(52): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5 {main} thrown in /usr/www/maxtingle/Blog/System/Core/Functions.php on line 177
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `DELETE` always deletes an entire row, so specifying the fields to delete makes no sense.

You want:

```
DELETE FROM BlogPosts WHERE Id=?
```

Comment: Sorry, I hit save by accident before removing the `*` - fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `*`, you delete the whole row:

`DELETE FROM BlogPosts WHERE Id=?`